# Excel VBA sumif

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working VBA script but I recently added a new IF statement and now it won't post the sumif value.  I'm trying to get the Lauren Comp section to populate the sum of that IF statement in the appropriate row in the AQ column.

```
Sub CalculateCommission()
    Dim Index As Integer    'Row Index
    Dim employeeName As String 'A
    Dim compPlan As String  'B
    Dim baseWage As Double  'AM
    Dim commAN As Double 'AN
    Dim guarantee As Double 'AO
    Dim earningsDue As Double   'AQ
    Dim priorPay As Double 'AR from prior pay cycle
    Dim priorBase As Integer 'AS from prior pay cycle
    Dim newComm As Double   'AU
    Dim packBack As Double 'AP

    Index = 3

    Do While Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Index))
        employeeName = UCase(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Index))
        compPlan = UCase(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Index))
        baseWage = ActiveSheet.Range("AM" & Index)
        newComm = ActiveSheet.Range("AU" & Index)
        earningsDue = ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index)
        guarantee = ActiveSheet.Range("AO" & Index)
        packBack = ActiveSheet.Range("AP" & Index)

'set to zero if there's an error - based on prior pay cycle

        If (IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("AR" & Index)) = False) Then
            priorPay = ActiveSheet.Range("AR" & Index)
        Else
            priorPay = 0
        End If

        If (IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("AS" & Index)) = False) Then
            priorBase = ActiveSheet.Range("AS" & Index)
        Else
            priorBase = 0
        End If

        commAN = ActiveSheet.Range("AN" & Index)

'base plus commission,else

        If compPlan = "B" Or compPlan = "D" Or compPlan = "E" Or compPlan = "I" Or compPlan = "J" Or compPlan = "L" Then
                commAN = earningsDue - baseWage - guarantee - priorBase
            Else
                commAN = earningsDue - baseWage - guarantee
        End If

'Lauren comp

        If compPlan = "L" Then
                Sumact = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("C:C"), "Doe, John", Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("D:D"))
        End If
            ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = Sumact

'base plus commission, else

        If compPlan = "B" Or compPlan = "D" Or compPlan = "E" Or compPlan = "I" Or compPlan = "J" Then
            If baseWage + newComm > baseWage Then
                earningsDue = baseWage + newComm + guarantee + priorBase - priorPay + packBack
            Else
                earningsDue = baseWage + guarantee + packBack
            End If
        Else
            If newComm > baseWage + priorPay Then
                earningsDue = newComm - priorPay + guarantee + packBack
            Else
                earningsDue = baseWage + guarantee + packBack
            End If
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = earningsDue
        Index = Index + 1
    Loop
EndSub:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = Sumact
ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = earningsDue
```

both look like they write to this cell. Are you sure in the "L" case , earnings due is not blank and overwriting your sumact value? it does not look like there is any condition that would prevent the second line from running if the first line also ran.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've tried just about everything and can't get a value to populate. The others calculate fine except for somebody who is labelled an "L". I feel like the "L" section does the calculation but doesn't say where to put the answer. I think there needs to be a statement along the lines of earningsDue = sumact. Does that make sense?

Comment: the "L" section tells the program to write to the AQ cell 'sumact' But 15 lines down the cell is set = to earningsdue. 

i would get rid of the fist AQ= sum act line and change the bottom line to :

` iIf complan= "L" then
ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = Sumact
Else
ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = earningsDue 
end if `

Comment: Wow!  That worked.  Best of all it almost makes sense to me  :)  Thank you so much